# Payload of a message: Id or full object

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, nservicebus, azure-eventgrid

**What are the pros and cons of sending the Id or the full object in a message?**

If I send a message with about an Order + Orderlines from system A to system B I can send the full order or first store the Order and then send the Id. I'm not sure which one to choose.

### Sending full object

Pros

- No need  to store the object first on the sending side
- No need to retrieve the object on the receiving side

Cons

- ?

### Sending Id

Pros

- The receiver can get the latest version of the thing being sent

Cons

- Object must be stored first
- Object must be retrieved
- The receiver doesn't have the data from the moment of sending, but from the moment of handling the message

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Sending the data in the message whenever possible